# Plotting time stamp column versus another column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am .xls file and i have column of timestamp with following format of timestamp

```
   2018-04-01 00:01:45
   2018-04-01 00:16:45
   2018-04-01 00:31:46
   2018-04-01 00:46:45
   2018-04-01 01:01:46
   2018-04-01 01:16:45
   2018-04-01 01:31:50
   2018-04-01 01:46:45
   2018-04-01 02:01:46
```

I Have another column with in same .xls file by name of temperature with following format

```
34
34
34
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
```

I want to plot values versus time . I tried to plot it but i am having issues in plotting it as it is not correctly reading the timestamp

My code :

```
#changing timestamp data from object to datatype
    w = df['Timestamp']
   // column name "Timestamp" was creating issue so i have to remove it"
    w=w.drop(w.index[0])
    //converting timestamp type object to datetime
    w = pd.to_datetime(w)

    area = (12 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii
    plt.xlabel('Temperature')
    plt.ylabel('DateTime')
    plt.title('Temperature and DateTime Relation')
    plt.scatter(t, w, s=area, c='purple', alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

Its Giving me error "TypeError: invalid type promotion"

Comment: Please share your code that is working incorrectly

Comment: Thanks for your response .I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I believe need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format` first and then for `15Min` data add `resample` with some function like `mean`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

s = df.resample('15Min', on='date')['temp'].mean()

s.plot()
```